# How do you use Codeunit 8618 Config. Excel Exchange to use Rapid Start to import an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-dynamics

We have successfully used C/AL code to run multiple Rapid Start packages from a Processing Only report. Now we need to reverse the process and upload the Excel files back into Dynamics NAV. The codeunit exposes 3 methods, ImportExcel, ImportExcelFromConfig and ImportExcelFromPackage. Can anyone explain which is the best method to use if we have a RapidStart.xlsx file to upload? Any code would also be appreciated as we have not been successful finding any documentation on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread which after a lot of trial and error became a workable, albeit a bit kludgy solution. [Error on Importing rapid start Configuration Package file in business central](https://community.dynamics.com/business/f/dynamics-365-business-central-forum/359835/error-on-importing-rapid-start-configuration-package-file-in-business-central)

We used a non-processing report to download an Excel file and then users updated it. The file was so large we had to split it into smaller pieces which would run for about 10 minutes during import. We created the files from Excel VBA but no matter what format we used on the Workbooks.SaveAs function, we would get fatal errors pertaining to Xml parsing when we tried to upload them into Nav using Rapid Start. The solution was to create an Excel template from an empty Excel file Exported from Dynamics NAV. This way the file is set up internally to be usable by Rapid Start.

The non-processing report has a NumberOfFIelds variable on the request page and that is used to create a For Next loop with a Confirm inside so the user can cancel if they so desire. The codeunit code prompts for a file each time thru the loop. It uses the following Tables and Codeunits:

Tables

1. Config. Package Table 8623
2. Confg. Setup 8627 (Temporary)

Codeunits

1. Config. Excel Exchange 8618
2. Config. Package - Import 8620
3. Config. Validate Package 8621

   ```
    LOCAL DoImportPriceChanges()
    FOR Count := 1 TO NumberOfFiles DO BEGIN
      IF Count > 1 THEN BEGIN
        IF NOT CONFIRM('Import next file %1 of %2?', TRUE, Count, NumberOfFiles) THEN BEGIN
          BREAK;
        END;
      END;

      ConfigPackageTable.SETRANGE("Package Code", RapidStartSalesPrices);
      IF ConfigExcelExchange.ImportExcelFromPackage THEN BEGIN
        UpdatedCount += 1;
        ConfigPackageTable."Package Code" := RapidStartSalesPrices;
        ConfigValidatePackage.RUN(ConfigPackageTable);
        TempConfigSetup."Package Code" := RapidStartSalesPrices;
        ConfigPackageImport.ApplyRapidStartPackage(TempConfigSetup);
      END ELSE BEGIN
        MESSAGE('Error importing Rapid Start package.');
      END;
    END;

    IF UpdatedCount = NumberOfFiles THEN BEGIN
      MESSAGE('%1 files were imported into Dynamics NAV.', NumberOfFiles);
    END ELSE BEGIN
      MESSAGE('Processing was incomplete. %1 out of %2 files were processed.', UpdatedCount, NumberOfFiles);
    END;
   ```